# Unix Shell Scripting - Loop until files are not found

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing shell script. I need to check specific directory for files existence with 2 specific file extension "eob" and "inp", and if exists I want to stay in the loop and keep on checking until files do not exist, then I want to break from my loop and proceed with the rest of the logic.

Below is the code I have so far, but it is not working...

```
while true
do
  [ ! find /home/mpcmi/cm -type f \( -name "*.eob" -o -name "*.inp" \) ] && break
  echo "eob or inp file exists"
  sleep 2
done
echo "eob or inp file doesn't exists"
```

First, I am getting this error when running the script:

```
"/home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator"
```

Second, it checks and finds the files with these extensions correctly I suppose because I am getting the output: "eob or inp file exists" however when I delete my test "eob" and "inp" files the script doesn't seem to detect it, it stops printing "eob or inp file exists" but it never prints "eob or inp file doesn't exists"

Below is the entire output, then it just stops after I delete test "eob" and "inp" files:

```
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
employees_load.sh[9]: /home/mpcmi/cm: unknown test operator
eob or inp file exists
```

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which shell you use. I assume it is bash.

1. You shall use '[[' and ']]' instead of '[' and ']' to evaluate whether the result of the 'find' command is empty or not.
2. You shall use '`' around the 'find' command to execute and feed the result to the evaluation above.

Here is the modified script:

```
while true
do
  [[ ! `find /home/smb -type f \( -name "*.eob" -o -name "*.inp" \)` ]] && break
  echo "eob or inp file exists"
  sleep 2
done
echo "eob or inp file doesn't exists"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bash` and that the files are not in a subdirectory

```
shopt -s nullglob
while true; do
    unset f
    f=( /home/mpcmi/cm/*.{eob,inp} )
    if (( ${#f[@]} > 0 )); then
        echo "${#f[@]} eob or inp files present"
        sleep 2
    else
        break
    fi
done
echo "no eob or inp files"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your logic:

```
while find /home/mpcmi/cm -type f \( -name "*.eob" -o -name "*.inp" \) | 
    grep -q . ; do
  echo "eob or inp file exists"
  sleep 2
done
echo "No extant eob or inp files"
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for responces!

Question - how do I make it to only look in /home/mpcmi/cm directory and NOT drill down to sub-directories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This prints exists if a file with .inp or .eob exists, and does not exist otherwise.

```
 if ls *.inp || ls *.eob
 then
     echo "exists"
 else
     echo "does not exist"
 fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Only in bash, without creating sub-process in the loop:

```
check_dir=/home/mpcmi/cm

my_tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir=/tmp)    # Create a unique tmp dir for the fifo.
mkfifo $my_tmp_dir/fifo                  # Empty fifo for sleep by read.

found=1
while [[ $found == 1 ]]; do
  found=0
  for f in $check_dir/*.inp $check_dir/*.eob; do
    [[ -e $f ]] && found=1 && break
  done
  read -t 1 <> $my_tmp_dir/fifo          # Same as sleep 1, but without sub-process.
done

rm $my_tmp_dir/fifo; rmdir $my_tmp_dir   # Cleanup, could be done in a trap.
```

By avoiding a `sleep` in loop, I do not create any sub-processes, so I am saving system resources.  To achieve that, I have to implement my own `sleep` in bash, and I only found `read` with a timeout on a fifo.

You can improve this script by using `trap` for the cleanup.